# Understanding recursive lazy lists

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get comfortable with the following snippet from the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Postponed):

```hs
primesPE = 2 : oddprimes
  where 
    oddprimes = sieve [3,5..] 9 oddprimes
    sieve (x:xs) q ps@ ~(p:t)
      | x < q     = x : sieve xs q ps
      | otherwise =     sieve (xs `minus` [q, q+2*p..]) (head t^2) t

minus (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of
  LT -> x : minus xs (y:ys)
  EQ -> minus xs ys
  GT -> minus (x:xs) ys
minus xs _ = xs
```

I'm getting tripped up on the recursive definition of `oddprimes` and the usage of `minus` on infinite lists by a function that is doing so recursively.

I think partly I'm confused because I do not understand how the Haskell compiler executes this code. How does it not run out of memory? I suspect the answer is `<magic> lazy evaluation </magic>` but I think I need a firmer grasp on how this is evaluated in practice to feel comfortable.

Comment: [This thread in the Programmers Stack Exchange site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/304019/how-does-repeat-x-xrepeat-x-return-a-list-in-haskell/) might be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Haskell systems usually represent values in memory by a kind of structure called a **thunk**.  Think of a thunk as an object that has two states:

1. Uncomputed
2. Computed

An uncomputed thunk contains a pointer to the object code subroutine that computes its result, and a pointer to the thunks that supply the values needed to perform that computation.  (If you've come across the concept of [**closures**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), an uncomputed thunk is a closure.)

A computed thunk just contains a raw result value.  The basic operation on thunks is called *forcing*.  When you force an uncomputed thunk, its subroutine is called with the captured arguments, the thunk is replaced with the computed result value (thereby switching its state to computed), and that value is returned.  When you force an already computed thunk, you just get the already computed value.

Maybe this is easier if we write in pseudocode.  I'll do something Java-ish:

```
class Thunk<A> {
    private final Supplier<A> computation;
    private boolean computed = false;
    private A result;

    Thunk(Supplier<A> computation) {
        this.computation = computation;
    }

    public A force() {
        if (!computed) {
            result = computation.get();
            computed = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That's not exactly like what what I described above, but it does behave like it.

Now, let's look at a simpler example, a function that constructs a repeating list of one element:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat a = a : repeat a
```

The `repeat` function gets compiled to an object code routine that, in pseudo-code, might look something like this:

```
Thunk<List<A>> repeat(Thunk<A> a) {
    return new Thunk<A>(() -> new Cons<A>(a, repeat(a)));
}

class Cons<A> extends List<A> {
    Thunk<A> head;
    Thunk<List<A>> tail;
    // ...
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with Java 8, `() -> new Cons<A>(a, repeat(a))` is a lambda.  This one is a function that takes zero arguments and, when called, constructs a pair.  The recursive call to `repeat` is *inside the lambda*, so calling `repeat` doesn't recurse—it returns a `Thunk` that captures the lambda, without executing it right away.  When that thunk is `force`d, only *then* will the lambda be called, which will call `repeat`, which will return another similar thunk right away.

Basically, in Haskell, code gets compiled to an optimized low-level version of this.

Comment: I like to think of lazy evaluation in terms of rewriting terms from the outside in. Do you know how to connect these perspectives concisely?

Comment: @dfeuer You could say: Lazy evaluation provides the denotational semantics for evaluation of haskell expressions. The design of the GHC runtime system with thunks provides one possible interpretation (sometimes called a *sharpening*) of this denotational semantics as an operational semantics.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, I guess it would probably be fair to say that term rewriting gives the denotational semantics (call by name), and graph rewriting gives the operational semantics (call by need). But it seems likely easy to get from one to the other by writing terms on paper, and replacing variable references with drawn arrows. I've never actually looked at how this is formalized though.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah... *elaborate shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, indeed, simply lazy evaluation. Haskell doesn't evaluate anything, not even the tail of a list, unless it's explicitly marked as strict, or if it is needed by an IO action (and even IO actions themselves may be lazy, which sometimes is confusing)

So, if you evaluate something like

```
head (1 : undefined)
```

You'll get 1, even though there's an undefined in there, because the tail of the list is never evaluated.